# Cannot install gnuplot with aquaterm support (OS X Yosemite)

Tags: osx-yosemite, gnuplot

I'm having issues trying to get aqua term support in gnuplot.
I've installed aquaterm, rebooted the system, then installed gnuplot using homebrew. 
When I start gnuplot, it sets terminal to 'unknown' and aquaterm isn't listed as one of the terminals.

I've also tried compiling gnuplot from source like this:

```
./configure -with-aqua
```

But when looking at the standard output, it says this:

```
aqua terminal: no
```

How do I get gnuplot with aquaterm support?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by setting the install flag `--with-aquaterm`, not `-with-aqua`

```
brew install gnuplot --with-aquaterm
```